# extract text with formatting preserved in php

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, extract

I am using [pdfparser](http://pdfparser.org/) I want to extract data from pdf in php such that it preserves all  the whitespaces. Currently it just returns the string from pdf removing all the formatting.

this is what i did

```
function extract_data($filename)
{
      $parser=new Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
      $pdf=$parser->parseFile($filename);
      $text=$pdf->getText();
      return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**$text=nl2br($page->getText());**
*echo $text;*

*Well this can easily be solved by replacing your last line with the last line I have provided ...*

Comment: Okei, But it won't print formatted text same as PDF,
Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: i am having same problem, if anybody knows the solution  about it please share.